# How can I import eclipse JDT classes in a project

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-jdt

I want to do the following imports in a class.

```
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.*;  
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.CharOperation;  
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.IProblem;  
import org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ClassFile;  
import org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.CompilationResult;  
import org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler;    
import org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.DefaultErrorHandlingPolicies;  
import org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ICompilerRequestor;  
import org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFileReader;  
import org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFormatException;  
import org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.env.ICompilationUnit;  
import org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.env.INameEnvironment;  
import org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.env.NameEnvironmentAnswer;  
import org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.impl.CompilerOptions;  
import org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.problem.DefaultProblemFactory;  
import org.eclipse.jface.text.Document;  
import org.eclipse.jface.text.BadLocationException;  
import org.eclipse.text.edits.TextEdit;
```

How can I import the JDT within Eclipse?
Cheers.

Comment: Did any of the solutions work for you?  Curious what you ended up doing.

Comment: Are you going to accept an answer yet? Or did none of them work? If so, then please comment on those answers or make an edit to your question to explain why the answers are not working.

Answer (score 15):

I think I found an easier way to do this:

- right-click on your project in the Package Explorer;
- choose "Build Path...";
- choose "Configure Build Path";
- choose the Libraries tab;
- click the "Add Variable..." button;
- in the list box, choose the "ECLIPSE_HOME" entry, and then click the "Extend" button;
- in the list box, open up the "plugins" folder entry, scroll way down, and shift-click all the org.eclipse.jdt.* JAR files that are in the file listing *beneath* the folders;
- click OK until you're all the way back out.

That should do it.

Comment: That might not survive an Eclipse migration, as you're going to be adding version-specific JDT JAR files to your classpath.

Comment: JDT can be used in stand-alone app, but it is a good practice to use it in a Plug-in. Because you also frequently need Java Model which is only supported in a plug-in.

Comment: I've found the jar files in my local P2 repo: e.g. `%USERPROFILE%\.p2\pool\plugins`

Comment: Just add into pom                                                                                                              <dependency>                        
          <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
    <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
    <version>4.6.1</version>                                                   </dependency>

Answer (score 3):

Unless I'm misunderstanding you, you just need to include the JDT JAR files on your classpath; they're all available in your Eclipse plugins directory.  So for your project, right-click on the project's name in the Package Explorer, go to the Build Path... submenu, and choose Configure Build Path.  Then in the Libraries tab, use the "Add External JARs" button to add each of the relevant JAR files from the Eclipse plugins directory.

Comment: Is there a way to add the whole of Eclipse's path to the classpath and/or buildpath and not add each individual jar?

Comment: See my next answer -- I think I found an easier way.

Answer (score 2):

If your'e writing plugins for Eclipse, you shouldn't really be trying to instantiate the `internal` packages. According to this [API Rules of Engagement](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-API-Use/index.html)

> Stick to officially documented APIs. Only reference packages that are documented in the published API Javadoc  for the component. Never reference a package belonging to another component that has "internal" in its name---these are never API. Never reference a package for which there is no published API Javadoc---these are not API either.

For the others, add the package name to the `Import-Package` entry in your manifest.

There are extension points into the JDT, but if what you want to do falls outside of these, then I'm afraid you're out of luck.

If you're just looking to use a compiler in your code, without relying on the JDK (i.e. on a JRE), then I would consider shipping with a more standalone Java based Java compiler like [Janino](http://www.janino.net/).

Answer (score 1):

If you need these classes, you are probably in a plug-in project already. You should be able to import these classes by applying the quick fix "Fix project setup..." (Ctrl+1) on the line where Eclipse is complaining about the imports. That will add the required plug-ins to your MANIFEST.MF file in the META-INF directory (org.eclipse.jdt.core and org.eclipse.jface.text in your case). You can also add them manually in your MANIFEST.MF file. If your project is no plug-in project (and you have no MANIFEST.MF file) you can convert it by right-click on the project -> PDE Tools -> Convert Projects to Plug-in Project first. If you add dependencies to plug-in projects in the normal way ("configure build path") the classloading won't work properly at runtime (though it will compile).