# Java parser with control-flow enumeration

Tags: java, parsing, control-flow, sat-solvers

Is there an open-source java parsing tool that can enumerate control flow paths through a method and compute range constraints on integer variables? (A Sat-solver would be great as well)

--EDIT --

[This is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5414221/15441) that triggered this question.

This is [the commercial version of the tool](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) I'm thinking of.

My question is - what is the closest open source equivalent?

Comment: I don't know of any, but the keywords to google for would be *abstract interpretation integer intervals*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A close approximation to what your asking for is the [Java Symbolic PathFinder](http://babelfish.arc.nasa.gov/trac/jpf/wiki/projects/jpf-symbc). From the site:

Symbolic PathFinder

- Performs symbolic execution of Java bytecodes
- Handles complex math constraints, data structures and arrays, multi-threading, preconditions, strings (on-going work)
- Applies to (executable) models and code
- Generates test vectors and test sequences that are guaranteed to achieve user-specified coverage (e.g. path, statement, branch, MC/DC coverage)
- Measures coverage.
- Generates JUnit tests, Antares simulation scripts, etc. (output can be easily customizable)
- During test generation process, checks for errors
- Is flexible, as it allows for easy encoding of different coverage criteria
- Is integrated with simulation environment (on-going work)

As to your second question, there is a native Java SAT solver: [sat4j](http://www.sat4j.org/)