# Workspace closed error when trying to use resources/projects outside Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I'm using Eclipse ast/jdt as is explained in this post - [How can I use the java Eclipse Abstract Syntax Tree in a project outside Eclipse? (ie not an eclipse plugin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964747/how-can-i-use-the-java-eclipse-abstract-syntax-tree-in-a-project-outside-eclipse)

The problem is that I always get null when I tried to use `resolveBinding()`, and it's because of not using `setProject(IJavaProject) or setEnvironment(String[], String[], String[], boolean)`, as is written in this post - [VariableDeclarationFragment node resolveBindind() returns null in eclipse/jdt/ast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755640/variabledeclarationfragment-node-resolvebindind-returns-null-in-eclipse-jdt-as)

Solving the returning null issue, I tried to use the code but ended up getting an error saying `Workspace is closed`.

What might be wrong?

[image]

I have .project file in the my workspace

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>AstRewrite4</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not in a Plug-In/Bundle Runtime, so the org.eclipse.core.resources plug-in wasn't "started". Initialization of the Workspace and associated objects only happens then.  You'll have to call the start() method on ResourcesPlugin yourself--not that I'm promising that'll solve everything, or that that's not going to cause you other problems.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Or, could you give me some links to understand how to do it?

Comment: It's complaining that the workspace is closed.  Have you tried calling Workspace#open()?