# How to create import in generated java files?

Tags: java, import

I'm working with an API that generate a lot of java code to me.

But this API does not handle import correctly, so it write full qualified name of every class. eg:

```
public class Foo{
    com.my.company.Bar bar;
    public com.my.company.Bar getBar(){
      return bar;
    }
}
```

I would like to find an API to post process this generated code and write something like that:

```
import com.my.company.Bar;

public class Foo{
    Bar bar;
    public Bar getBar(){
      return bar;
    }
}
```

Is there any known API able to do that?

Comment: What IDE are you using ?

Comment: I'm integrating this into a maven process.

Comment: And I'm working on IntelliJ

Comment: What are you using to generate the code?

Comment: Spoon http://spoon.gforge.inria.fr/

Answer (score 0):

Filtering imports from existing code isn't trivial; imagine you have two classes with the same name but different package.

My usual approach is to have a helper class which manages the imports for me. In the generator, I can

```
String type = importSet.add(Foo.class);
```

`type` is then used in the method to access the type. The import set collects all imports and handles duplicates.

For this to work, you need this "main loop":

```
importSet = new ImportSet();
String body = generateClass();

out.write(importSet);
out.write(body);
```

i.e. you need to generate all the code for the class itself (collecting the imports as you go) *first*. Then you write the imports to the file and after that the generated class body.

If you want to change the sources, I suggest to use the [Eclipse Java compiler](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/guide/jdt_api_compile.htm) because it can give you the AST of the code. You can then apply various transformations on this tree. I have an [example in my blog how to get the AST](http://blog.pdark.de/2010/11/05/using-eclipse-to-parse-java-code/).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see you expect to generate Java code right? If yes . We are using `Eclipse JDT` in our project which is from `Eclipse IDE` and they use it for **Java code generation**. And I encourage to use it, however depending on need you might go for simple solution like `QDox` or even other solution.

You can consider either one of the solution

- Eclipse JDT
- Javaparser
- Qdox

**Eclipse JDT**

**Pros**

- Impressive functionality
- Very rich API
- Support for Java 7 features and they have a plan to also support Java 8 features
- Localizable syntax error messages

***Con's***

- Steep learning curve

Resources
Intro to Eclipse JDT

http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-JavaCodeManipulation_AST/index.html

How to use JDT API outside eclipse

[How can I use the java Eclipse Abstract Syntax Tree in a project outside Eclipse? (ie not an eclipse plugin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964747/how-can-i-use-the-java-eclipse-abtract-syntax-tree-in-a-project-outside-eclipse)

Nice example and project on AST

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ast/

Access Eclipse jar plugin sources

http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseCodeAccess/article.html

Test samples

http://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.core.git/tree/org.eclipse.jdt.core.tests.model/src/org/eclipse/jdt/core/tests

**Qdox**

**Pro's**

- build from scratch and modify
- lightweight
- FQN type based searching
- clean and readable API
- extensive querying possibility like isFinal(), isPrivate()
- object oriented constructs, almost everything in a java file can be represented in terms of objects like, JavaClass, JavaField, JavaMethod, JavaParmeter

**Con's**

- last public release was 1.10 on 2009-09-04, how ever 2.0 snapshot is available
- 1.10 is not supporting static import;
- writing to a file is pre-formatted, don't have much control over it, can't specify the line numbers
- no article or tutorial, source code is the only reference

Resources
 - Qdox http://qdox.codehaus.org/changes-report.html