# How to use eclipse JDT plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I installed JDT plugin (I'm running Eclipse 4.2.1) but Eclipse doesn't recognize some types and classes. For example I got "CompilationUnit cannot be resolved to a type".
Do I have to import something Eclipse doesn't suggest?

Comment: See [How can I import eclipse JDT classes in a project][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93728/how-can-i-import-eclipse-jdt-classes-in-a-project

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are trying to use the JDT libraries in an eclipse plugin project, you will have to add the `org.eclipse.jdt.core` to the plugin dependencies (in the plugin.xml file).

Else if you are trying to add these to a java application, then you will need to add these to the build path.

Right click on the project and select *Properties > Build Path > Add External JARs*

Here just add the jdt libraries from the Eclipse plugins directory.

Answer (score -1):

You have to `import` packages you are using. In this specific case:

```
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.CompilationUnit;
```

(if that's the `CompilationUnit` you are talking about, it's the first hit on Google).

Eclipse can find the correct `import` automatically for you by pressing `Ctrl-Shift-O`. (Something I really miss in Visual Studio 2010).

Comment: I tried but I got `The import org.eclipse cannot be resolved`