# M2 Eclipse Maven3 pom generate classpathentry relative to ECLIPSE_HOME

Tags: maven, classpath, tomcat7, maven-3, m2eclipse

How do I get this kind of classpath entry:

```
<classpathentry kind="var"  path="ECLIPSE_HOME/plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.debug_3.7.100.v20120529-1702"/>
```

generated when loading my maven project in eclipse?

I am currently working with an embedded Tomcat7 project and need the jdt plugin jars added on the classpath when running in eclipse (per [How can I import eclipse JDT classes in a project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93728/how-can-i-import-eclipse-jdt-classes-in-a-project)). I don't want developers loading this project to have to manually make these classpath entries.

I have been looking at:
http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-update-my-classpath-with-an-eclipse-user-library-via-the-maven-eclipse-plugin.html

but this doesn't seem right since I am not using a classpath container?

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/eclipse-mojo.html

Doesn't seem to have an option to make a manual classpath entry like this?